# How to make gitlab run jobs in sequential order?

Tags: gitlab

I have a `gitlab-ci.yml` file like the following:

```
stages:
  - test
  - job1
  - job2


test:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
  script:
    ...

myjob1:
  stage: job1
  script:
    ...


myjob2:
  stage: job2
  script:
    ...
```

According to the documentation [HERE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rules-clauses) (or at least how I understood it), the first stage/job is only run when I create a merge request.

This is true, but the next stage (`job1`) is run ***in parallel*** when the first job (`test`) has been started. As far as I understand the stages which are defined in the order `test` -> `job1` -> `job2`) always run in sequence.

So what am I doing wrong? Why do job `test` and `job1` run in parallel, and not in sequence as expected?

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of trial-end-errors and reading and rereading parts of the really unclear and confusing [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html) I might have found a solution.

First, the stage you only want to run on a merge request (or which you do not want to run if you schedule a trigger or start the pipeline manually), you need to change that stage as follows:

```
test:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - when: on_success
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'echo "Running Test"'
    - 'echo $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE'
```

Here, you define a rule that checks if the variable `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` is either `web` or `schedule`. If the variable is `web` this means a manual pipeline trigger (i.e. you pressed manually on `Run pipeline`, which is **not explained** in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)), or if the pipeline is triggered by a schedule (not tested, but I assume that is what `schedule` means).

So if the pipeline is triggered by a scheduled event or manually, `never` tells gitlab to not execute that stage. The `when: on_success` is like an `else` statement, which tells gitlab to run that stage in any other case.

However, that is not the complete story. Because when you use `git` to make changes to the code and push it to gitlab via `git push`, you have **two triggers** in gitlab! A trigger `merge_request_event` and a trigger `push`. That means, the pipeline is started *twice*!

To avoid the pipeline started twice you need to use the `workflow` key, which helps to define if the pipeline (=workflow) is run or not. (The term `workflow` seems to mean `pipeline`). Here is the code to be put into the `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - when: always
```

This construct suppresses the pipeline to be run when the trigger is `merge_request_event`. In that case, the additional pipeline is not run. In all other cases (when the trigger is e.g. `push`), the pipeline is run.

So here is the complete `gitlab-ci.yaml` code:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - when: always


stages:
  - test
  - stage1
  - stage2


test:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      when: never
    - when: on_success
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'echo "Running Test"'

my_stage1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - 'echo "Running stage 1"'


my_stage2:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - 'echo "Running stage 2"'
```

If you make a `git push` then one pipeline is run with the stages `test`, `my_stage1` and `my_stage2`, and when you start the pipeline manually or if it is triggered by a schedule, one pipeline is started with the stages `my_stage1` and `my_stage2`.

As to why this is so complicated and confusing, I have not the slightest idea.

Comment: This might make pipeline slightly less confusing: https://dev.to/jphi_baconnais/gitlab-cheatsheet-1-basics-of-stages-and-jobs-14p0